# Show order details in a new column on My account / order table

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, orders

In WooCommerce, I would like to add a new column to the "My Account" orders table and show the order details.

I have this code, which adds the column, but the values don't show (e.g. get_formatted_meta_data).

Can anyone help rewrite the code to make it work?

```
function wc_add_my_account_orders_column( $columns ) {
    $new_columns = array();
    foreach ( $columns as $key => $name ) {
        $new_columns[ $key ] = $name;          
        if ( 'order-status' === $key ) {
            $new_columns['order-details'] = __( 'Order details', 'textdomain' );
        }
    }
    return $new_columns;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns', 'wc_add_my_account_orders_column' );

function wc_my_orders_order_details_column( $order ) {
    $order_details = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'order_details', true ); 
    echo ! empty( $order_details ) ? $order_details : '–';        
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_order_details', 'wc_my_orders_order_details_column' );
```

Answer (score 1):

The `woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns` filter has been deprecated since WooCommerce 2.6.0. So although it still functions you should use the `woocommerce_account_orders_columns` filter to add an additional column.

To populate the column with your data you can use the `woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_` action which expects you to append the column ID of your custom column. So in your case that would be `order-details`. In your example you've used `order_details` (with an underscore instead of a hyphen). That is why your data doesn't show up.

Also it is best practice to retrieve order meta data via the internal WooCommerce getter function `get_meta()` instead of using `get_post_meta()`.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_orders_columns', 'wc_add_my_account_orders_column', 10, 1 );
function wc_add_my_account_orders_column( $columns ) {
    $new_columns = array();
    foreach ( $columns as $key => $name ) {
        $new_columns[ $key ] = $name;          
        if ( 'order-status' === $key ) {
            $new_columns['order-details'] = __( 'Order details', 'textdomain' );
        }
    }
    return $new_columns;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_order-details', 'wc_my_orders_order_details_column', 10, 1 ); 
function wc_my_orders_order_details_column( $order ) {
    $item_meta = '';
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        $item_meta .= wc_display_item_meta( $item, array( 'echo' => false ) );
    }
    echo !empty( $item_meta ) ? $item_meta : '-'; 
}
```